# Which module(s) should I use to create a customer support section?

Tags: 7

I've got a site where I need to get a customer (**not client**) support system set up. [Support Ticketing System](http://drupal.org/project/support), unfortunately, is geared towards client support. I think Storm is too (it's huge, in any case).

The way I see it, I've got a few options:

- Set up a different installation of Drupal entirely and use something like OpenAtrium or Drupal Commons for the support area. OMG overkill. Plus I'd like to just have it be a coherent part of my current site, same theme and shared logins and all that.
- Patch Support ticketing system, or Storm, or whatever module I wind up using.
- Use CaseTracker + Mailhandler to get a simple system, but I'll probably wind up still needing to do an amount of configuration to get it working.
- Give up and use something like [Trellis Desk](http://www.accord5.com/trellis) on a subdomain.

One thing that maybe makes my search a little harder is that I'm adamant about having inbound email integration. The same way that we do, customers want to email an address and get a support ticket created. If this functionality isn't there, they'll send an email.

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested?

Comment: It's enough to use the relative tag.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for cleaning it up. I sure am glad Drupal StackExchange appears to have the equivalent of path_redirect when the aliases change :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Similar Module Review page](http://groups.drupal.org/node/17948) and choose the one that works best for you.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'd checked out that page already. I'm asking here because none of those are really good enogh. They don't assume both that the site *itself* is the main topic of the support section (or the one particular thing on it, in this case a service it provides). Is there something similar to Trellis Desk or Kayako eSupport for Drupal or am I better off using one of those and not trying to do this in Drupal? I'm OK with that - I just want to do due diligence before going that route.

Comment: Case tracker and support modules are pretty much stable. I have used it in the recent past. I am not sure about Trellis Desk or Kayako eSupport perhaps  you can play around its hook to extend it for your needs or hack it if not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I contacted the maintainer of Support ticketing system to see about joining forces. If I'm going to struggle through this, I want to give something back the community. It feels strange to use a third-party product. That's my last resort. For now I have the issue queue anyway as a workaround since the service I need this for has a Drupal module. I'll award you the answer...since it's basically the answer in terms of what Drupal has at the moment.

Comment: If you are considering support module beware of db_affected_rows(). I had duplicate insert and key error problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the [Feedback](http://drupal.org/project/feedback) module used with great success, I would recommend trying it out.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm looking for something that I could to set up more of a dedicated support area. It seems like Feedback is for giving page-specific Feedback. I may be wrong; could you describe more why you recommended that? I'm commenting based on having seen it used on a site before and having looked at its project page and screenshots.